# ./d2j-dex2jar.sh Not found

Tags: java, apk

I have installed all the files. sh but I keep giving this error I can do?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S5Hxv.png)

Comment: What part of "java: not found" do you struggle with?

Comment: I have installed java

Comment: But it looks like Java is not in the path, or JAVA_HOME isn't pproperly set. How did you install Java? From a package that came with your distro or with a package from the Oracle website?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, setting JAVA_HOME as usual won't do unfortunately. You need to set the java binary to be accessible anywhere in the terminal by adding it to your $PATH like so:

```
export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin
```

Then it should work fine :)